# The ``/`` character is not allowed in object names

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

I am working with a structure within the HDF5 file that has names with '/' in them. When I load said file, I get this warning:

```
 ⓔ  develop  In [1]  import pandas as pd

 ⓔ  develop  In [2]  store = pd.HDFStore('data/XXX-20150423-071618.h5')       

 ⓔ  develop  In [3]  store
/home/XXX/virt/env/develop/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tables/group.
py:1156: UserWarning: problems loading leaf ``/log``::

  the ``/`` character is not allowed in object names: 'XXX/align/aft_port_end/extend_pressure'

The leaf will become an ``UnImplemented`` node.
  % (self._g_join(childname), exc))
```

We *could* change those but it would be a major PITA and would involve hacking existing critical files.  So, while possible we would like not to do that.

Is there any way we can have '/' in names or is it just not supported?

```
>>> pd.show_versions()

INSTALLED VERSIONS
------------------
commit: None
python: 2.7.5.final.0
python-bits: 64
OS: Linux
OS-release: 3.10.0-229.1.2.el7.x86_64
machine: x86_64
processor: x86_64
byteorder: little
LC_ALL: None
LANG: en_GB.UTF-8

pandas: 0.16.0
nose: 1.3.6
Cython: 0.22
numpy: 1.9.2
scipy: 0.15.1
statsmodels: None
IPython: 3.0.0
sphinx: 1.2.3
patsy: None
dateutil: 2.4.2
pytz: 2015.2
bottleneck: None
tables: 3.1.1
numexpr: 2.2.2
matplotlib: 1.4.3
openpyxl: None
xlrd: None
xlwt: None
xlsxwriter: None
lxml: None
bs4: None
html5lib: None
httplib2: None
apiclient: None
sqlalchemy: 0.9.7
pymysql: None
psycopg2: None
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically the file is illegal HDF5 - the [official spec in 5.2. HDF5 Path Names and Navigation](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc1.6/UG/03_Model.html) clearly defines `Name`s to be strings of non-slash characters. So, PyTables isn't wrong to reject your input here (and it's being rather gracious by simply falling back to an `UnImplemented` node).

That said, if you're not afraid of just hacking PyTables, you could disable the offending check from [`tables/path.py`](https://github.com/PyTables/PyTables/blob/13047c897d28b7278cbeab732f12feadbfef3f22/tables/path.py#L91). As far as I can tell, the only side-effect of this will be that the objects will not be usable using natural naming, but that's not likely to be a big deal.

(Caveat: I have not used PyTables before, so this is based solely on my reading of the code.)

Comment: GAH! I'll have harsh words with the other devs... ^_~ Many thanks indeed.